# Update external state using tensorflow autograph and tf.function

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm creating a layer that is a variation on batch normalization and using the `tf.function` decorator to speed it up. However, I'm getting an error that says autograph doesn't know whether or not I want to reuse the variable that I'm trying to update.

```py
class MyClass(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def build():
        self.foo = self.add_weight(...)

    @tf.function
    def call(inputs, training=None):
        lst = [K.moving_average_update(self.foo, .5, .999)]
        self.add_updates(lst)
```

This throws an error that is something like:

```
ValueError: Variable my_class/foo/biased already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?
```

What is the idiomatic way to tell autograph to reuse state outside the function?

Comment: Could you please try passing the argument `getter = lambda **kwargs: tf.get_variable('var_name', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE, **kwargs)` to `self.add_weight`?

Comment: @rvinas would `var_name` be `foo` in this case or would it be `var_name` always.

Comment: It's just the variable name, so they both should make it

Comment: @rvinas I gave it a shot, but `get_variable` is deprecated in 2.0

Comment: Alright - can you pass a `tf.Variable` instead? For example, create a function with arguments `**kwargs` returning a `tf.Variable` being created within the block `with tf.variable_scope('scope', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)`, and then pass the function to the argument `getter` of `self.add_weight`.

Comment: @rvinas could you provide an example because I'm not quite sure what you're getting at.

Comment: Sure. I posted an example (in this case, I am not using `add_weight` for simplicity -using `tf.Variable` should yield the same results)

Answer (score 0):

In order to reuse the variable `self.foo` you could define within a tf.variable_scope block, setting the argument `reuse = tf.AUTO_REUSE`. For example:

```
def build(self, input_shape):

    with tf.variable_scope('scope', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        self.foo = tf.Variable(initial_value=YOUR_INITIAL_VALUE, name='var')

    trainable = None  # True or False
    if trainable:
        self._trainable_weights.append(self.foo)
    else:
        self._non_trainable_weights.append(self.foo)
```

**NOTE:** Not tested.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no `variable_scope` in 2.0 and there is no `tf.AUTO_REUSE` constant.

Comment: Could you please try appending `tf.compat.v1` to these functions? (e.g. `tf.compat.v1.AUTO_REUSE`)? (see [migration plan](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180817-variables-20.md#migration-plan))

Comment: Actually. It's working now without any modifications. Worked once I bumped to the stable release of 2.0.